# How is the eye damaged by computer screens?

Tags: human-eye

Eyes are damaged by persistent use of computer screens. On giving it some thought, it felt quite magical that your eyes are damaged simply by looking at something. I googled where there were articles about blue light and stuff and having felt dissatisfied come to the wiser community here for help.

The question is pretty plain, **how does the simple action of looking at a computer screen cause damage to the eye? Is it due to focussing the eye continuously at something close-by?**

Is the damage caused to the retina, or the cornea or some other part and in what form? Does the light reshape the lens or something?

**Edit:** I got glasses of power +1 for both eyes about 3 years ago and 4 years ago, my exposure to computer screens increased to about 6 hours a day. Before that, it was hardly an hour or two a week. The ophthalmologist I consulted also credited it to increased exposure to computer screen.

Hope the questions are clear.

Comment: You really need to support the claim that eyes are damaged by computer screens in particular - that is, aside from the problems caused by spending extended periods focussing on any close work.

Comment: @jamesqf Sorry but, I'm not getting what you are trying to express.

Comment: You need to show some credible source that looking at computer screens damage the eyes. Without it, your question is a wild guess.

Comment: How old are you? Becoming long-sighted is nothing unusual with age.

Comment: I am barely 18 years:)

Comment: Re your edit, being rather older than common access to computer screens, I remember that the same thing would be said about people who'd spend a lot of time reading, or doing other close work like sewing.  IOW, it's not something unique to computer screens, but to the muscular effort involved in keeping the eyes focussed on something close.  Eventually they adapt to it.

Comment: The light from computers is safe, it can only be the distance and the reading habit which are a problem, so the same applies to books. avoiding excercising your eyes in their near and far ranges is known to be a problem, that's why reading is not recommended to those with growing eyes.

Comment: This would be better placed at skeptics.